# Need advice on improving testability

Tags: spring, testing, junit, software-quality

I have developed a stack of web Services based on:

- Spring ws 2.0 with jaxb2 maven plugin (to ease the pain).
- Hibernate.
- PostgResql.

We are using the following to test:

- Junit test with Mockito.
- Spring test for Dao & service layer.
- The new Spring ws test & Smock api.
- SoapUi Api for testing with their maven plugin.

We have TracWiki for the wiki side.

All is fully automated in a maven build with Hudson, even the deployment of the webapp with cargo
on distant server.
We have 5 virtual servers on a single machine on Debian (using vserver).

We don't have a single performance test and we don't have any webapp tools to monitor.

**What do you recommend to go a step further?**

I'm really looking for new ways and/or tools to improve everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey.
Incorporate [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) into your builds. You will get lots of informations about your code.

Comment: +1, being able to see the history of **every** metric is priceless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you mentioning any code coverage tools. While coverage isn't everything, it can help finding the parts of your code which aren't covered by the tests (or perhaps even dead).